# Programatically setting Horizontal alignment of Dock Panel

Tags: c#, silverlight

So far I have:

```
myDockPanel.SetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);
```

I know `TextAlignment.Center` is not right.  Does anyone know what this should be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myDockPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`HorizontalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) property as defined by a [`DockPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx) (and all [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx)) takes a [`HorizontalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.horizontalalignment.aspx) for values.  It should be:

```
myDockPanel.SetValue(DockPanel.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
```

Comment: Why not just set the property directly: `myDockPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center`?

Comment: @Metro: Well yes I could have.  But I wanted to keep my example in the same style as the posted code.

Comment: M - Fair enough. In this case, I don't think the OP understands there is no need to set the property directly through the `DependencyObject`.

Comment: @Metro: Good point.  Then he would have seen what the type really was then.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Horizontal Content Alignment" property for the `DockPanel` control. If you intend to set the **`HorizontalAlignment`** property instead, then you could either use

```
myDockPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

or

```
myDockPanel.SetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
```

which are do pretty much the same thing since the property setter for the `HorizontalAlignement` (first example) calls the `SetValue` on the object (the second approach).

Just make sure you have a using statement for `System.Windows` namespace.

Hope this helps :)